# Split CSV into groups based on value

Tags: php, python, csv

i have this CSV

```
idSensor,ReadData
1010,1459
1010,1477
1011,1307
1011,1183
1012,1050
1012,1015
1013,575
1013,474
```

And i want to transform this CSV into this :

```
1010,1011,1012,1013
1459,1307,1050,575
1477,1183,1015,474
```

Can you guys help me to transform my CSV in python or PHP language?

Comment: Can you explain why your output has to be in this order exactly?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this site; SO is not a code-writing service.  You can submit your attempt to solve the problem, and ask questions about the problems you are having with your code.

Comment: The output has to be in this order because i want to import the csv to HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Python 2 and Python 3.

Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to group the rows by the value in the first column, and then some clever [zipping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) of the dictionary's keys and values to produce the required format:

```
data = [s.split(',') for s in '''1010,1459
          1010,1477
          1011,1307
          1011,1183
          1012,1050
          1012,1015
          1013,575
          1013,474'''.split()]

from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for key, value in data:
    d[key] = d.get(key, []) + [value]

grouped_data = [row for row in zip(*[[k]+v for k,v in d.items()])]
for row in grouped_data:
    print(','.join(row))
```

**Output**

```
1010,1011,1012,1013
1459,1307,1050,575
1477,1183,1015,474
```